# Configuration for liquidbase to generate more than one changeSet file

Tags: java, spring-boot, liquibase, liquibase-cli

I'm trying to find a way for liquidbase to be able to generate different files with its changeSets in order to historicize the different changes that are made in the database in different files. That is, if on day one, I have only one entity in the database, and I generate its corresponding changelog, it generates a file with that entity. If the next day I generate a new entity, and I generate its changelog again, it generates a file with the data of entity 1 and entity 2.

Is there no way that the files that are generated only have the new changes in the database?

I'm generating the files with 'liquibase-maven-plugin'